# Insert data using Merge and auto increment value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I am inserting data by `MERGE` statement and it is working, but when I am auto increment value in insert then it is always getting **NULL**

```
MERGE INTO tblSectionTemplate Trg
USING 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT MAX(ID) AS ID,
    MAX(REPLACE(Section,'''','"')) AS Section
    FROM #TmpTenQKData
    GROUP BY Section
    ORDER BY ID
) AS Src 
ON UPPER(TRIM(Trg.Section)) = UPPER(TRIM(Src.Section)) AND Trg.TickerID = @TickerID

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT 
    (
        TickerID,
        Section,
        Active,
        insertdate,
        OrderID
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        TRIM(@TickerID), 
        TRIM(Src.Section), 
        'A', 
        GETDATE(), 
        (SELECT MAX(ISNULL(OrderID,0))+1 FROM tblSectionTemplate WHERE TickerID=@TickerID)
    );
```

I am talking about this area which is not working as expected. `(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(OrderID,0))+1 FROM tblSectionTemplate WHERE TickerID=@TickerID)`

When inserting data then I am checking **MAX OrderID of particular data based on ticker id**.
When first time inserting data then there is no data for that **tickerid**. So **OrderID will be null** and I add +1. Second time insert it should get value for order id and I add +1.

But after insert when I am checking the table value **I found NULL is inserted always for orderid field**.

Please tell me where I made the mistake. How could I insert value into order id field **incremented by 1**.

Comment: If there is no row with `TickerID = @TickerID`, then the query returns no rows at all. You need `ISNULL((SELECT MAX(...) ...)` for that.

Comment: can you please full code for this line `ISNULL((SELECT MAX(...) ...)`

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.